# Run git command in Jenkins failing

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

GIT_COMMIT is returning null, so I tried to run the following command:

```
env.GIT_COMMIT = sh(script: "git rev-parse HEAD", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

I am now getting the following error:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I do have my git repo in my Jenkins workspace. Where am I supposed to run the shell script?
I have multiple stage looking like:

```
stage('Checkout GIT')
stage('Do something else')
stage('Do an other thing')
```

I've been trying to run the shell command in one of these 2 last stages

Comment: "I do have my git repo in my Jenkins workspace". Maybe cd into the repo.

Comment: Run the command `sh "ls -la"` to debug the existence of the `.git` folder...

Comment: do you run `checkout scm` before the shell commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also specify the location of your repo by wrapping your git commands into dir:

```
stage('Checkout repo') {
  steps {
    dir ("{env.WORKSPACE}/<path_to_repo>") {
      script {
        <your code here>
       ...
```

Comment: I had to remove {env.WORKSPACE} but other than that, this fixed my issue. Thank you